# How often do futures load network data?

Tags: flutter, future

Im interested to know how often a future loads data form the network. Im going to use flutter for example because i work with it. Say you launch a screen A that loads data from a network. You then navigate to anew screen B then you pop screen B and back you are to A. Does the future in A load data again.
Ps.If you could be detailed on how often data is loaded i would appreciate.

Comment: It depends on how you are using that `future` and what type of future it is. Also, the logic on your app, if you don't want to fetch again, use state-management, for images some widgets already capable of handling cache.

Comment: Yeah +1, it totally depend and what you need and how you code it ... But a future is not a stream, it success/fails onnly once.. depending on where you initialize/remove it from your widget tree